# Can I convert Traffic Overlay Google Maps to JSON / XML?

Tags: android, google-maps

Can I convert Traffic overlay google maps JSON/ XML? Because i want search the road / area name in my apps for android, and i want get traffic from google maps but in JSON / XML type.

Example: Sudirman Road, Indonesia.

Result: Red - Traffic Jam (in JSON/ XML/ Text).

Any solutions?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't. The best you get is in the JavaScript Maps API, you get a layer that is directly rendered on the map. But due to licensing restrictions from the originators of the data, it is not possible for Google to provide the data directly to you.